# Platform is not visible when register app on MobileFirst Server 8

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Hi I recently updated MobileFirst Version from `7` to `8` and the application working perfectly on `MobileFirst Development Kit Server` (with Android, iOS, Browser Environment).

But after I have deploy to on premise MobileFirst Server version 8. What happened is the only environment or platform that visible on server is iOS as you can see in screenshot below.I have successful deploy all 3 platform but the other two platform not visible

[image: MobileFirst]

We couldn't find any information on IBM knowledge Center website

Thank you.

Comment: How did you "deploy" ? Did you use the CLI ? If so, what is the CLI command you used. Can you provide the output of the CLI command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if, during installation of IBM MobileFirst Platform Server 8.0 ( using Installation Manager), you select the option `"Install IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation for iOS"` in the General settings panel. If this option is chosen, iOS will be the only platform visible in the MobileFirst Operations Console.

Once the choice has been made during installation, you cannot reset it later. You will have to uninstall and re-install , and choose not to select "for iOS" option. Keep the default option (No) as-is in the Install IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation for iOS section of the General settings panel.

Details on each step during installation, can be found in this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_install_gui_mode.html).